# Fatal error: Call to a member function query()

Tags: php, mysqli

someone can tell me where am I wrong? why i have this message "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object" when i try call query function? thank you :)

```
class Connection extends mysqli {

 protected $user;
 protected $password;
 protected $database;
 protected $host;
 protected $querymia;
 protected $link;



 function __construct($user,$pass,$database,$host){
    $this->user=$user;
    $this->password=$pass;
    $this->database=$database;
    $this->host=$host;


    $this->link= mysqli_connect("$this->host","$this->user","$this->password","$this->database") or die("Error");


 }

 public function InsertQuery($string,$table){


  $this->querymia = 'INSERT INTO' . "$table" . 'VALUE' . '(' . "$string".')' ;
  $this->link->query($this->querymia); 


 }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedural `mysqli_connect` returns a handler, *not* an object.

Therefore, you should be using `mysqli_query($this->link, $this->querymia);`

Comment: No, it still returns a regular mysqli object, which can be used interchangeably in procedural or OO mode.

Answer (score 0):

The whole error should state: `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object`. So `$this->link` is not an object. Maybe the connection couldn't be estabilished.

You should add some code like:

```
if (!$this->link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

after calling `mysqli_connect()` or before calling `query()`;

Comment: mmmh no the connection is ok, 
I want to distinguish the database connection in the costructor and query in the function, I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: Your code is ok. Just add this before `$this->link->query($this->querymia);`

Comment: sorry, what should I add before? :)

Comment: hello,I resolved, the real problem is that i instantiated the children class but not parent class (whit connection database), thanks you to all!